# A question concerning the definition of a local function

Tags: differential-geometry, dynamical-systems, quantum-field-theory, local-field

What is the exact definition of a *local* function? Is a function said to be local if it depends only on the value of its variable, and a finite number of derivatives of this variable, at a single point? For example, $$f(y(x),y'(x),\ldots,y^{(n)}(x);x)$$ or is there something else to it?

The reason I ask in particular is to do with defining the meaning of a Lagrangian density in physics; as far as I understand, a Lagrangian density (dependent on some field $\phi(x)$ is *local* if its value at a given spacetime point $x^{\mu}$ is dependent only on the value of the field, and its derivatives (to finite order), evaluated at that *single* spacetime point $x^{\mu}$, $$\mathcal{L}(x)=\mathcal{L}(\phi(x),(\partial_{\mu}\phi)(x),\ldots,(\partial^{(n)}_{\mu}\phi)(x))$$ and this definition of local is *not* physical, but purely a mathematical definition of locality. (At least according to Matthew Schwartz's book *"Quantum Field Theory and the Standard Model"*, chapter 24, section 4).

Is this definition of locality borrowed from the notion of local coordinate charts and neighbourhoods in differential geometry at all?

(This is probably not the right place, but I assume that this definition is purely mathematical and *not* physical, because physically, the quantum fields $\phi$ are technically distributions and so cannot be localised to a single point in space, however, such a mathematical definition guarantees desired properties, such as Lorentz invariance, an absence of *action-at-a-distance*, etc?)

Comment: In GR, Local functions are functions defined at each point p, noted $$\xi_p$$ the cardinality of local analytic functions is $$\aleph_1^{\aleph_1}=\aleph_2$$ which is much more than normal analytic functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, your interpretation is correct.

Let $F_1$ be a fibre bundle over $M_1$ and $F_2$ be a fibre bundle over $M_2$; denote by $\Psi_{1,2}$ the corresponding space of smooth sections. A map $f:\Psi_1\to \Psi_2$ is said to be *local* if it factors through a bundle map $\tilde{f}: J^k\to F_2$ where $J^k$ is the $k$-th jet bundle of the fibre bundle $F_1$.

In your physical interpretation, you should think of the Lagrangian density itself as a "distribution" over your space-time manifold, and that each field is itself a "distribution" over your space-time manifold. And the mapping from field to Lagrangian density is in general a mapping from some set of distributions to some other set of distributions. This is the physical point of view! In other words, the Lagrangian density takes, physically, the entire wave function/field as input, not the "value" of the field at an arbitrary point. And the codomain of this Lagrangian density function is some set of distributions over your manifold, not just some number or some finite dimensional vector.

Imposing the locality condition is just saying that mathematically you can compute the "value" of the Lagrangian density at a space-time point $p$ based only on the "values" of the first few derivatives of the field at the point $p$. The main advantage of this, when it comes to mathematics, is that then the associated equations of motions are partial differential equations.

If you allow "non-local" dependences in the Lagrangian density your equations of motions would become either delay-differential equations or integro-differential equations or some combination thereof, and those are much harder to solve or analyze in general when compared to straight-up partial differential equations. Hence imposing the locality condition is *mathematically convenient*; if you want to actually use QFT to compute things, you might as well assume the locality condition, since if you don't, things get really hard.

Related: [Peetre's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peetre_theorem)

---

If you go back to the basics of all these, which is calculus of variations and the principle of least action, all you really need for the action functional is that for each quantum field (thinking in terms of it as an object defined over the space-time) your action returns a number. There's not even originally the requirement that the action be necessarily obtained from integrating a Lagrangian density. In principle you can just think of the action functional as a function defined over some infinite dimensional vector space (the state space) and your job is to find a critical point for this function.

Mathematically the representation of the action by a Lagrangian density and the requirement that the mapping from the field to the density is local, are mainly "simplifying assumptions"; they simplify the situation since we know how to use the Euler-Lagrange technique to convert the condition of "critical point of the functional" to the condition of "solving a PDE". And solving PDEs is sometimes easier than doing calculus in infinite dimensions.

Physically there may or may not be good axiomatic justification for these requirements. But at the very least, experience has shown that under these assumptions we can still formulate interesting physics that reasonably model the real world. And so there is really no need to consider the more general picture just to make life more difficult when it comes to computations.

Comment: So is the idea that physically the dynamics of a given system at a given point should only depend on the local behaviour of the physical quantities pertaining to that system. This can then be described mathematically by requiring that the Lagrangian density you construct to describe the dynamics of the theory should depend only on the values of the fields at said given point along with the values of their derivatives at that point (this allows one to reconstruct the local behaviour of the fields via a Taylor expansion)...

Comment: ...If this were not the case and one were required to know the behaviour of the field at two (or more) arbitrarily separated points then this would require knowledge of the global behaviour of the field, which renders the theory useless. Would this be correct at all?

Comment: @Will Everything up to the last sentence I think is fine. _If_ you accept that physical theories must be local in the sense you described, then this mathematical imposition is a must. The only thing I don't 100% agree with is that "...require knowledge of the global behaviour of the field, which renders the theory useless." Whether a scientific theory (or mathematical model thereof) is useful is ultimately judged by how well it predicts experimental outcomes. For me "useless" is too strong a word in this situation.

Comment: Ok cool. Would it be better to say that if one were required to know the behaviour of the field at two (or more) arbitrarily separated points then this would require knowledge of the global behaviour of the field, which would severely complicate calculations?

Comment: @Will: that's a fair statement. I would probably say "nonlocal" instead of "global"; but that's just a personal taste thing.

Comment: Ah ok, thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

One thing is a function defined locally, which is related to the notion of local coordinate charts. Another thing is a function whose values at a given point only depend on the local properties of its arguments. Yet, your notion for a lagrangian in field theory is a third type, where the arguments themselves might be a function and its derivatives.

As an example, if one think of the Levi-Civita connexion associated to a (pseudo)riemannian manifold $(M,\mathrm{g})$ as a function (usually referred to as a mapping, but this nothing more than nomenclature) 
$$\nabla^\mathrm{g}:\mathfrak{X}(M;\mathbb{R})\oplus_{C^\infty(M;\mathbb{R})}\mathfrak{X}(M;\mathbb{R})\to\mathfrak{X}(M;\mathbb{R}) \ , $$ 
that takes two vector fields on $M$ and returns another vector field on $M$, one notice that this function is well defined over the whole of $M$ (meaning that it is well defined in the domain $\mathfrak{X}(M;\mathbb{R})\oplus_{C^\infty(M;\mathbb{R})}\mathfrak{X}(M;\mathbb{R})$), although its values at a point only depends on the values of the vector fields (serving as arguments) at a point and its derivatives: i.e. $\nabla^\mathrm{g}(X,Y)\big|_p\in T_pM$ for some pair of vector fields $X,Y\in\mathfrak{X}(M;\mathbb{R})$ and point $p\in M$ depends only on $X\big|_p,Y\big|_p\in T_pM$ and on the first derivatives of the components of $Y\big|_p$ (written in any basis) at the point $p$. Because of that, the Levi-Civita connexion can be though of an example of a function that at a given point only depends on the local properties of its arguments.

For lagrangians (or even more generally, but from this I believe anyone can picture what the other cases are) and not being very rigorous, they could depend on the values of the integral of a field over some region, and this is an object whose values depend not only on what happens in a neighbouring region, but on the whole region where the integral of the field is being computed, e.g. $\mathcal{L}(x)=\partial_\mu\partial^\mu\phi+\int_R\phi^2dx^1\cdots dx^n$, where $R$ is some region where the scalar field $\phi$ is defined.

Comment: why do the arguments have to be evaluated at a single point though? Why couldn't they be evaluated at points that are infinitesimally close to one another? Is this from physical arguments or a requirement in the mathematical description of locality?

Comment: Sorry, about what exactly are you referring to?

Comment: I mean, for example, why must it be $\mathcal{L}(\phi(x),(\partial_{\mu}\phi)(x))$ and not something like $\mathcal{L}(\phi(x),\phi(x+\delta x))$, or $\mathcal{L}(\phi(x),\phi(y))$?

Comment: It can be. This is something that depends on the explicit formula for your lagrangian. The physical idea of locality is that if the value of your lagrangian at a point depends on the values of the fields on far away points, then it is nonlocal.

Comment: I've read though that the definition of locality being that the Lagrangian density is a function of the field values (and their derivatives) at a single point is purely a mathematical definition and not a physical one. What is the reasoning behind this?

Comment: locality is a pure physical notion that can be described by pure mathematical definitions, as velocity. Another issue is whether or not the pure mathematical definitions are good enough to encompass a large amount of physical models of nature.

Comment: That's what I thought but Matthew Schwartz, in his book "Quantum Field Theory & the Standard Model" states the following in Chapter 24, section 4: "We take locality to mean that the Lagrangian is an integral over a Lagrangian density that is a functional of fields and their derivatives evaluated at the same point." And then he further elaborates: "To be clear, this definition is mathematical, not physical: it is a property of our calculational framework, not of observables." This has caused me confusion.

Comment: Yes, they provided a mathematical definition that describes the physical notion of locality for some physical models of nature. If their definition allowed for lagrangians depending on the values of the fields at various points far away from each other, they would not be achieving a mathematical definition that respects the physical notion of locality.

Comment: Ah OK, it just seemed (at least when I read the whole paragraph) that the author was trying to distinguish this definition from a physical one and I thought that he meant in the sense that the quantum fields themselves are not physically observable and cannot be localised to single points, but are rather localised distributions?!